# What's a word for reporting a situation in a worse light than it merits?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be such a word? For example, imagine a situation in which person A tells their friend (person B) that a window in their house cracked and that cost of replacing it is somewhat expensive. This friend then goes on to tell their friend (person C) of person A's unfortunate occurence. Instead of simply stating that a window cracked, he reports it as "the window exploded and repairing it will potentially lead him to financial bankruptcy". So, what would be a word for what person B just did? Something like "exaggerate", but with a negative connotation, as "exaggerate" can be pretty neutral.

Thanks!

Comment: See synonyms of _exaggerate_, then tell us why none of them fit the purpose. :)

Comment: Perhaps "dramatize" would be useful in this context?

Answer (score 2):

The usual word is *[sensationalize](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sensationalize)* -- "to present information about (something) in a *sensational* way:"

> Presenting information in a way that is intended to provoke
>   interest and excitement, at the expense of accuracy

Comment: +1  This is what came to my mind as well.

Comment: But it doesn't have a negative connotation (which the question specifically requested).

Answer (score 1):

A good word to use might be *Embellish*, which would fit quite nicely as it's often used specifically when referring to stories.

Embellish Via [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/embellish)

> To make something more beautiful or interesting by additions or
> details: Many early building entrances were richly embellished. ​ If
> you embellish a story or statement, you add details that are not
> completely true in order to make it more interesting: "He couldn’t
> resist embellishing his account of the African safari"

Another befitting word would be *Dramatize*, which has a more negative connotation.

Dramatize Via [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?&q=define%20dramatize)

> Exaggerate the seriousness or importance of (an incident or
> situation): "They have a tendency to dramatize things"
>
> Synonyms: exaggerate, overdo, overstate, hyperbolize, magnify,
> amplify, inflate

Comment: But it doesn't have a negative connotation (which the question specifically requested).

Answer (score 0):

***Dramatize*** -- [Vocabulary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dramatize)

> To dramatize something is to put it in dramatic form (like a TV show or movie) or make it seem more dramatic, using exaggeration.
>
> Anytime you see a movie or TV show about real events, the actors are dramatizing what really happened. If you slipped on the sidewalk and hurt your knee a little but later made it sound like the most tragic event in the history of humanity, you're guilty of dramatizing what happened.

Comment: But it doesn't have a negative connotation (which the question specifically requested).